# Is there a way to generate test report in robot framework which says total test case = 0, passed = 0 , failed = 0?

Tags: robotframework

When we run test suites using a tag say "ABC" and if none of the tests are matching the given tag, there will be no report generated.
But is there a way to generate report that says zero test cases were executed in robot framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is option to do exactly that, just add option **--runemptysuite** to your command.Here's [a link](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#when-no-tests-match-selection)

```
robot --runemptysuite --include ABC test.robot
```